# Connect a private EC2 to a FSx OpenZFS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-fsx

I'm trying to connect a EC2 instance to a FSx of file system type OpenZFS, my EC2 only have private IP, I configured a route table on the subnet of the FSx, but when I try to mount

```
sudo mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=4.1 my-fs /fsx
```

from my EC2 I got this error

```
mount.nfs: Connection timed out
```

what else should I setup before can I access to my FSx?

Comment: try to show the mounts from the FSX with the command:
'showmount -e nfs-server-ip'
 it's hard to answer, we need more info regarding the network, do you have 2 VPCs ot 1? have you checked the security groups?

Answer (score 0):

You can try first with "showmount -e nfsserverIP"
to make sure that NFS is open between the EC2 and the FSX,

if nothing is there, then you need to check the Security group and the mount command

try to do the mount command like that:
sudo mount -t nfs -o vers=4.1 FSX_endpoint/fsx